# Tkinter Cant remove image lines

Tags: image, tkinter, background

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.configure(background = 'red')
root.geometry("400x480")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("box.png"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack()
```

It shows the icon BUT it shows the icon with white lines on the edge:

[image: Check here]

So is there any way to remove those lines or **atleast** change the color?

Comment: Are you aware that the label widget has many options, some of which explicitly are for modifying its appearance? Also, the code you posted won't result in the image you've linked to.

Comment: Are you using a `Canvas` or something, somewhere?

Comment: try setting the border width of the label to 0 like this: `panel = Label(root, image = img, border=0)`

Comment: @CoolCloud While editing please correct all mistakes in a post. For example, you didn't add the image in...

Comment: i thought i uploaded the image i fixed it now, also when i add the image as a label or a canvas the same thing happens so is there an option to remove the lines using canvas or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Flavio Moraes for giving me the answer! using border=0 removes the lines from the image like this

```
    panel = Label(root, image = img, border=0)
```

again thank you